Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Blue Screen while trying to install NVidia 555.85 WHQL (even clean install) through GeForce Experience
Here's my setup:
Intel Core 2 Quad Extreme Q9650 @ 3.00GHz:
Intel Mother Board DP45SG
Bios: Intel Corp. SGP4510H.86A.0125.2010.0121.1927, 1/21/2010
I have 8GB DDR3 Ram with 9/9/9/24 stepping
and an EVGA NVidia GTX 750 Ti 2Gb Super OC.

I had Windows 10 Pro installed on an older Hitachi 2TB Hard Drive and everything worked fine until yesterday Saturday, 5/25/2024 when I tried installing the latest version of NVidia's Driver through GeForce Experience and this is where I got my first Blue Screen. Then I tried reinstalling it while performing a Clean Install through the NVidia installer. Same result.
After experiencing this, I've had a brand new unopened 2TB Seagate Barracuda Drive sitting there for almost a month, so I finally broke down and decided to do a complete clean install of Windows 10 Pro.
I went through the entire process of installing Windows 10 Pro and went through all the preliminary setup and updates routine. After the clean install, basic configuration, and Windows Updates I was able to successfully install Razer's Synapse 3.0 with no issues.
I went back to NVidia's website to retrieve their latest official driver and when I checked against their list of supported devices / cards, sure enough my GTX 750 Ti is in that list.
But again, to no avail, the Blue Screen of Death.
I don't know if this is a NVidia issue or a Microsoft issue. However, during the Blue Screen, it was pointing the error at nvlddmkm.sys. I don't know if this is a faulty driver install from NVidia, or if this is a faulty built in system library from Microsoft that communicates with the NVidia drivers, and this is now where I'm at.

Here's what I've done so far in tracking this thing down.
I tracked it Via:

Computer Managment ->

System Tools ->

Event Viewer ->

Windows Logs ->

System









And I found the Error with timestamp: 5/26/2024 5:42:55 AM Type: BugCheck
Here's the XML version:
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  - <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WER-SystemErrorReporting"
     Guid="{ABCE23E7-DE45-4366-8631-84FA6C525952}" 
     EventSourceName="BugCheck" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">1001</EventID> 
    <Version>0</Version> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>0</Task> 
    <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-05-26T12:42:55.6013130Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>731</EventRecordID> 
    <Correlation /> 
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
    <Channel>System</Channel> 
    <Computer>*****</Computer> // Personal Info Here 
    <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">0x0000007e (0xffffffffc000001d, 0xfffff806b8fd48ce, 0xffff9085d49cb478, 0xffff9085d49cacb0)</Data> 
    <Data Name="param2">C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP</Data> 
    <Data Name="param3">8e80260a-a15d-4a82-8da2-e68960db7ba1</Data> 
  </EventData>
</Event>


I then navigated to this directory:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_nvcontainer.exe_afa212b0a468b49fccba12218a1f9a78e3e9c872_a2b04090_ee63a6e4-feb8-4187-a8d8-cb90b9438178
And I opened this WER file by downloading, installing and opening it with Diagnostic Data Viewer and here's it's report for the NVidia Container: There's 34 of them, all the same
NVIDIA Container

Description
Faulting Application Path:   C:\Program Files\NVIDIA 
Corporation\NvContainer\nvcontainer.exe
Creation Time:           5/26/2024 6:09:54 AM
Problem:             Stopped working
Status:              Report sent

Problem signature
Problem Event Name:           APPCRASH
Application Name:             nvcontainer.exe
Application Version:          1.40.3345.4032
Application Timestamp:        653a1567
Fault Module Name:            nvapi64.dll
Fault Module Version:         32.0.15.5585
Fault Module Timestamp:       664264e9
Exception Code:               c0000005
Exception Offset:             00000000000e467a

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:           0e270761b06ec773a37722651e0c5618 (1402627626640365080)

And within the same WER File, here's the report for the shutdown crash:
Windows

Description
Faulting Application Path:   C:\Windows\System32\WerFault.exe
Creation Time:           5/26/2024 5:43:08 AM
Problem:             Shut down unexpectedly
Status:              Report sent

Problem signature
Problem Event Name:           BlueScreen
Code:                         1000007e
Parameter 1:                  ffffffffc000001d
Parameter 2:                  fffff806b8fd48ce
Parameter 3:                  ffff9085d49cb478
Parameter 4:                  ffff9085d49cacb0
OS version:                   10_0_19045
Service Pack:                 0_0
Product:                      256_1

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:           (18446744073709551615)


Last but not least, I also navigated to C:\Windows\ to find the memory.dmp file and downloaded, installed and opened it with WinDbg and within the debugger's Command tab, I clicked the link anaylyze -v to generate some basic debug information that I then exported to a text file which can be seen here:
************* Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories **************
   ExtensionRepository : Implicit
   UseExperimentalFeatureForNugetShare : true
   AllowNugetExeUpdate : true
   NonInteractiveNuget : true
   AllowNugetMSCredentialProviderInstall : true
   AllowParallelInitializationOfLocalRepositories : true

   EnableRedirectToV8JsProvider : false

   -- Configuring repositories
      ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true
      ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories completed, duration 0.000 seconds

************* Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize **************

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize completed, duration 0.032 seconds
   ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true, Packages count: 0
   ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true, Packages count: 41

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.27553.1004 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be available.

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Kernel base = 0xfffff804`08600000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff804`0922a7c0
Debug session time: Sun May 26 05:39:44.488 2024 (UTC - 7:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 2:07:16.217
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
..................................................
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
........................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff804`089fdaf0 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:0018:ffff9085`d49ca480=000000000000007e
1: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (7e)
This is a very common BugCheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.  Always note this address
as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffffc000001d, The exception code that was not handled
Arg2: fffff806b8fd48ce, The address that the exception occurred at
Arg3: ffff9085d49cb478, Exception Record Address
Arg4: ffff9085d49cacb0, Context Record Address

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 7015

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 7040

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 1030

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 18078

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 109

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.KiBugCheckData
    Value: 0x7e

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.LegacyAPI
    Value: 0x7e

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.TargetModel
    Value: 0x7e

    Key  : Failure.Bucket
    Value: 0x7E_C000001D_BAD_IP_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

    Key  : Failure.Hash
    Value: {640903f0-666e-41fb-f6d8-cbfd11e2ccf9}

    Key  : Hypervisor.Enlightenments.Value
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Enlightenments.ValueHex
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.AnyHypervisorPresent
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ApicEnlightened
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ApicVirtualizationAvailable
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.AsyncMemoryHint
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.CoreSchedulerRequested
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.CpuManager
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.DeprecateAutoEoi
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.DynamicCpuDisabled
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.Epf
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ExtendedProcessorMasks
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.HardwareMbecAvailable
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.MaxBankNumber
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.MemoryZeroingControl
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.NoExtendedRangeFlush
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.NoNonArchCoreSharing
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.Phase0InitDone
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.PowerSchedulerQos
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.RootScheduler
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.SynicAvailable
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.UseQpcBias
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.Value
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ValueHex
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.VpAssistPage
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.VsmAvailable
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.AccessStats
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.CrashdumpEnlightened
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.CreateVirtualProcessor
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.DisableHyperthreading
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.HostTimelineSync
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.HypervisorDebuggingEnabled
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.IsHyperV
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.LivedumpEnlightened
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.MapDeviceInterrupt
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.MceEnlightened
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.Nested
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.StartLogicalProcessor
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.Value
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.ValueHex
    Value: 0

    Key  : SecureKernel.HalpHvciEnabled
    Value: 0

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1


BUGCHECK_CODE:  7e

BUGCHECK_P1: ffffffffc000001d

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff806b8fd48ce

BUGCHECK_P3: ffff9085d49cb478

BUGCHECK_P4: ffff9085d49cacb0

FILE_IN_CAB:  MEMORY.DMP

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffff9085d49cb478 -- (.exr 0xffff9085d49cb478)
ExceptionAddress: fffff806b8fd48ce (nvlddmkm+0x00000000001248ce)
   ExceptionCode: c000001d (Illegal instruction)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

CONTEXT:  ffff9085d49cacb0 -- (.cxr 0xffff9085d49cacb0)
rax=0000000000000001 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=ffffe78aff2f58b0
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=ffffe78afd42b000
rip=fffff806b8fd48ce rsp=ffff9085d49cb6b0 rbp=0000000000000087
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=000000000000e4fc r10=00000000ffffffff
r11=000000000000001d r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=000000000000e4fc r15=ffffe78afd42b000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
nvlddmkm+0x1248ce:
fffff806`b8fd48ce f30fb8d8        popcnt  ebx,eax
Resetting default scope

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000001d - {EXCEPTION}  Illegal Instruction  An attempt was made to execute an illegal instruction.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c000001d

EXCEPTION_STR:  0xc000001d

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
nvlddmkm+1248ce
fffff806`b8fd48ce f30fb8d8        popcnt  ebx,eax

STACK_TEXT:  
ffff9085`d49cb6b0 fffff806`b8fcbcb7     : ffff9085`d49cb838 00000000`00000001 fffff806`b99ef5a0 fffff806`b9226b6a : nvlddmkm+0x1248ce
ffff9085`d49cb6e0 fffff806`b8fabc82     : ffffe78a`fd42b000 ffffe78a`fd42b000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000258 : nvlddmkm+0x11bcb7
ffff9085`d49cb710 fffff806`b98732aa     : ffff9085`00000000 00000000`0000e4fc ffffe78a`fd42ecb0 00000000`00000258 : nvlddmkm+0xfbc82
ffff9085`d49cb790 fffff806`b918247d     : ffffe78b`02a7c9a8 ffffe78b`02a7c9a0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x9c32aa
ffff9085`d49cb7d0 fffff806`b8f9ef77     : 00000000`00000040 ffffe78a`f998ec78 00000000`00000040 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x2d247d
ffff9085`d49cb820 fffff806`b8f9e884     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 ffffe78b`04182078 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0xeef77
ffff9085`d49cb8b0 fffff806`b8fa1f40     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff806`b9b31ae4 00000000`dd7bab00 : nvlddmkm+0xee884
ffff9085`d49cb8e0 fffff806`b8fd0ecf     : ffffe78a`fd42b000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff9085`d49cbb00 : nvlddmkm+0xf1f40
ffff9085`d49cb930 fffff806`b8f7f2f0     : ffff9085`d49cbab0 000006f1`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nvlddmkm+0x120ecf
ffff9085`d49cb9b0 fffff806`b8f7d2d2     : ffff9085`d49cdaa8 ffffe78a`f86604d8 000006f1`f12cb908 ffffe78a`f86604d8 : nvlddmkm+0xcf2f0
ffff9085`d49cce00 fffff806`ba36ed8d     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000e000 ffff9085`d49cd000 ffffe78a`f865e000 : nvlddmkm+0xcd2d2
ffff9085`d49ccf00 fffff806`ba2e770c     : ffffe78a`f865e000 ffff9085`d49cd320 ffff9085`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x14bed8d
ffff9085`d49cd220 fffff806`ba3b4a12     : ffff9085`d49cdaa8 ffffe78a`f97fca00 ffffe78a`00000003 ffffe78a`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x143770c
ffff9085`d49cd800 fffff806`ba3ca71b     : fffff806`ba3b493e ffffe78a`f865e000 ffffe78a`f86189e0 ffffe78a`fe08b180 : nvlddmkm+0x1504a12
ffff9085`d49cd8d0 fffff806`ba193eee     : 00000000`000000c8 fffff804`0f2ca3bd 00000000`00000001 00000000`74727044 : nvlddmkm+0x151a71b
ffff9085`d49cd910 fffff804`0f2ca633     : 00000000`000001e0 fffff804`08fb7074 ffffe78a`00000002 ffffe78a`fe08b030 : nvlddmkm+0x12e3eee
ffff9085`d49cd950 fffff804`0f2adbf8     : ffffe78a`f97fca00 00000000`00000080 ffffe78a`fe08b180 ffffe78a`00000000 : dxgkrnl!DpiDxgkDdiStartDevice+0x6b
ffff9085`d49cd9b0 fffff804`0f2c692c     : 00000000`00000080 ffffe78a`fe08b180 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : dxgkrnl!DpiFdoStartAdapter+0xb0c
ffff9085`d49cdb30 fffff804`0f2c65e0     : 00000000`00000001 ffffd2a1`c748ea81 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : dxgkrnl!DpiFdoStartAdapterThreadImpl+0x308
ffff9085`d49cdce0 fffff804`0894eb35     : ffffe78b`03770000 ffffe78b`03770040 00000000`00000080 fffff804`0f2c65b0 : dxgkrnl!DpiFdoStartAdapterThread+0x30
ffff9085`d49cdd10 fffff804`08a06af8     : ffffc001`e1f45180 ffffe78b`03770040 fffff804`0894eae0 00000000`00dbe690 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x55
ffff9085`d49cdd60 00000000`00000000     : ffff9085`d49ce000 ffff9085`d49c8000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x28


SYMBOL_NAME:  nvlddmkm+1248ce

MODULE_NAME: nvlddmkm

IMAGE_NAME:  nvlddmkm.sys

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffff9085d49cacb0 ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  1248ce

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x7E_C000001D_BAD_IP_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {640903f0-666e-41fb-f6d8-cbfd11e2ccf9}

Followup:     MachineOwner   

I'm not going to go as far as to show the 100s or 1,000s lines of assembly, but it appears to me, that an unknown function, or a not recognizable symbol is being called during the installation process of this driver.
Also, as a side note, I tried rolling back to the previous driver that worked beforehand by downloading it from NVidia's website, and doing a complete clean install which was 552.44 WHQL dated from May 9th, and to no avail, same result: BSOD!
Before this install I was able to play both No Man's Sky and Satisfactory. After the initial blue screen on the original hard drive, GeForce Experience was reporting that the 555.85 version was installed after Windows had restarted from the crash. I then opened Steam and tried to run No Man's Sky, and it was stating that it was either missing a Vulkan driver file or that it was corrupted and Vulkan worked just fine the night before. I didn't even try to load Satisfactory, and on this newer hard drive, I have not yet installed Steam.
I don't know which company is at fault here, but regardless of if it's MS or NV, if you're going to release an official updated set of drivers that potentially install at the kernel level, MAKE SURE THEY WORK FIRST! I'm not getting paid to do your debugging job!
Now, outside of that rant... Is there anyone else within the community that has had a similar situation and was able to get it fixed or working? I'm preferably looking for a complete working solution. If you need the entire memory.dmp file for modification let me know in a comment. Here's a read only viewing link: BSOD Crash Reports. If there's any additional information that you might need, please don't hesitate to ask.

The driver version is correct but the BSoD itself suggests problems with the old card.

Similar BSOD issue during installation with 555.* and 556.* drivers on a Core 2 Quad Q9550 based system. However, going back to 554.22 works fine.
As the issue is not widespread enough for nVidia to notice and fix over 3 versions of drivers, I assumed it's related to the older (Core 2) series of CPUs, that aren't that many still in use out there.
Update 2024-07-16: After some searching around I found this thread: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/game-ready-drivers/13/546931/geforce-grd-56070-feedback-thread-released-71624/
The important part is this: EOL Windows driver support for older CPUs without POPCNT instruction: https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5554
Basically support for the pre-SSE4.2 CPUs has been officially discontinued.
Update 2024-11-04: As per https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5554
On October 22nd, 2024, we released NVIDIA graphics driver version 566.03.  This newer driver uses an updated version of MSVC that resolves this issue.  If your PC uses an unsupported CPU, please download and install the latest NVIDIA graphics driver from the Drivers tab of the NVIDIA app, GeForce Experience or GeForce.com.

Having just lived through this whole voyage of discovery thing on older nVidia cards, it comes down to nVidia drivers making a decision to not support cards after a certain date, and CPU's also get caught up in it. For me, the solution to get back to rock solid performance on a core 2 pc with 980Ti, being assembled from old parts to gift to grand kids, was to use nVidia's beta and older driver facility and select the card, pick Std driver from dropdown, for which release 472 was the latest. Installed that and bsod's vanished, all solid again! This is the page link: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx and you can try the latest driver for your card, and try earlier ones if cpu is an issue. Whilst it is reported by others that the 554 driver works for the core 2 CPU (which I also have), if nVidia are saying nothing past 472 is worth having on a 980Ti, I expect they know what they are talking about!
